# Create a Stream using Scanner

Tags: arrays, java-8, java.util.scanner, java-stream

This is usually how I accept an `Array` from a user. I ask for the size, then loop and populate the `Array`.

```
Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
int N = scan.nextInt();
int[] numbers = new int[N];
for (int n=0; n<N; n++){
    numbers[n] = scan.nextInt();
}
```

I have been trying to learn java 8 and I noticed that the `Random` class has a method now to create a stream. It is pretty easy now to declare a n-sized array with random numbers.

```
int[] randomNumbers = new Random().ints().limit(N).toArray();
```

What I have been trying to do is create an array doing something similar with either streams or lambda expressions but for user input. What I tried doing is creating an `IntStream`, map the values to `Scanner#nextInt`, then create an array.

```
int[] numbers = new IntStream().map(x -> scan.nextInt()).limit(N).toArray();
```

What I *can* do is something like this:

```
int[] numbers = new int[N];
Arrays.fill(numbers, 0);
numbers = Arrays.stream(numbers).map(x -> scan.nextInt()).toArray();
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(numbers));
```

But that still feels a bit redundant. Filling the array with some arbitrary number only to replace it in the next line.

Comment: [Don’t do `.ints().limit(N)`](http://stackoverflow.com/q/33929363/2711488) on a `Random`. Use `ints(N)`; it will be more efficient when calling `toArray()` as it knows the array size in advance then.

Comment: @Holger I am not using the `Random` class. Was just an example. Thanks though for the heads up. Will keep that in mind when I use it in future projects.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Due to the [way, the current implementation handles `limit(…)`s](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33929363/2711488), it’s more efficient to create a stream using:

```
IntStream.range(0, N).map(i -> scan.nextInt())
```

which will be more efficient when using `toArray()` as well as for parallel processing despite creating an otherwise unused value with the `range` operation. Further, this creates an [*ordered* stream](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/package-summary.html#Ordering) which [maintains the element order](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29218074/2711488).

So when using,

```
int[] numbers = IntStream.range(0, N).map(i -> scan.nextInt()).toArray();
```

it benefits from knowing the array size in advance.

Comment: The range does the job of the fill basically from my example. Thanks for the clarification.

Comment: Please do come back and post here if you come up with a way without creating the unused values with the range operation.

Comment: Actually, every solution has to use such a value as it has to count somehow to limit the result to the desired number. You can only find solutions hiding it, e.g. the implementation of `limit` must have a counter somewhere. If you like hiding it, you can use `Collections.nCopies(N, scan).stream().mapToInt(Scanner::nextInt)`…

Comment: Right but there is a difference between setting the size of the array and creating a stream with n amount of sequential numbers. There should be a way to do this with using only one number (N) not N numbers.

Comment: I do like the `Collections` solution. Thanks for that as well.

Comment: There is no technical difference as streams do not materialize. `IntStream.range` does not “create” the numbers, it just performs the specified downstream action `N` times (or less in case of short circuiting operations) passing the current value of its counter. `IntStream.generate(…).limit(N)` will do the same but won’t pass the the counter to the action (and report different characteristics).

Comment: Would there be a way to do this with `Scanner#nextLine` and returning a `String[]` from the stream?

Comment: `String[] array=IntStream.range(0, N) .mapToObj(i -> scan.nextLine()) .toArray(String[]::new);`

Answer (score 3):

Use [`IntStream.generate`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/IntStream.html#generate-java.util.function.IntSupplier-):

```
int[] numbers = IntStream.generate(() -> scan.nextInt()).limit(N).toArray();
```

As mentionned in the comments, this generates an unordered stream. If you want it to be ordered, you can use:

```
IntStream.range(0, N).map(i -> scan.nextInt()).toArray();
```

Comment: Yup that did it. So basically use generate when we do not have values? and map when the stream is already filled?

Comment: Exactly, in your ``map``, you can see you do not use ``x`` so you basically need a ``Supplier<To>`` instead of a ``Function<From, To>``

Comment: Ahem, [`IntStream.generate`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/IntStream.html#generate-java.util.function.IntSupplier-) creates an *unordered* stream which is unlikely what you want here. While the current implementation won’t change the ordering for this use case as there’s no benefit in that for a sequential stream, this behavior still is not guaranteed…

Comment: @Holger never specified _ordered_ or _unordered_. This is what I am looking for.

Comment: @gonzo: ok, but in most cases, developers don’t want to have the elements in a different order than read from the `Scanner`, so this still should be mentioned for future readers, even if it’s ok for you.

Comment: @Holger please add your solution creating an `ordered` stream for future users.

Comment: @gonzo: as said, it’s unordered by definition (read [the API documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/IntStream.html#generate-java.util.function.IntSupplier-)) but you won’t notice in this specific use case. Still, it’s *not guaranteed*. See [Ordering](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/package-summary.html#Ordering)

Comment: @gonzo I added an ordered version :)