# Generate infinite parallel stream

Tags: java, java-8, rx-java, java-stream

### Problem

Hi, I have a function where i going to return infinite stream of parallel (yes, it is much faster in that case) generated results. So obviously (or not) i used

```
Stream<Something> stream = Stream.generate(this::myGenerator).parallel()
```

It works, however ... it doesn't when i want to limit the result (everything is fine when the stream is sequential). I mean, it creates results when i make something like

```
stream.peek(System.out::println).limit(2).collect(Collectors.toList())
```

but even when `peek` output produces more than 10 elements, `collect` is still not finallized (generating is slow so those 10 can took even a minute)... and that is easy example. Actually, limiting those results is a *future* due the main expectation is to get only better than recent results until the user will kill the process (other case is to return first what i can make with throwing exception if nothing else will help [`findFirst` didn't, even when i had more elements on the console and no more results for about 30 sec]).

### So, the question is...

how to copy with that? My idea was also to use RxJava, and there is another question - how to achieve similar result with that tool (or other).

#### Code sample

```
public Stream<Solution> generateSolutions() {
     final Solution initialSolution = initialSolutionMaker.findSolution();
     return Stream.concat(
          Stream.of(initialSolution),
          Stream.generate(continuousSolutionMaker::findSolution)
    ).parallel();
}

new Solver(instance).generateSolutions()
    .map(Solution::getPurpose)
    .peek(System.out::println)
    .limit(5).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Implementation of `findSolution` is not important.
It has some side effect like adding to solutions repo (singleton, sych etc..), but nothing more.

Comment: Can you provide a [Minimal, Verifiable, Complete example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to clarify your question?

Comment: Sample code added.

Comment: Somewhat related https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30825708

Answer (score 6):

As explained in the [already linked answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33936529/2711488), the key point to an efficient parallel stream is to use a stream source already having an intrinsic size instead of using an unsized or even infinite stream and apply a `limit` on it. Injecting a size doesn’t work with the current implementation at all, while ensuring that a known size doesn’t get lost is much easier. Even if the exact size can’t be retained, like when applying a `filter`, the size still will be carried as an estimate size.

So instead of

```
Stream.generate(this::myGenerator).parallel()
      .peek(System.out::println)
      .limit(2)
      .collect(Collectors.toList())
```

just use

```
IntStream.range(0, /* limit */ 2).unordered().parallel()
         .mapToObj(unused -> this.myGenerator())
         .peek(System.out::println)
         .collect(Collectors.toList())
```

Or, closer to your sample code

```
public Stream<Solution> generateSolutions(int limit) {
    final Solution initialSolution = initialSolutionMaker.findSolution();
    return Stream.concat(
         Stream.of(initialSolution),
         IntStream.range(1, limit).unordered().parallel()
               .mapToObj(unused -> continuousSolutionMaker.findSolution())
   );
}

new Solver(instance).generateSolutions(5)
    .map(Solution::getPurpose)
    .peek(System.out::println)
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: you make this sound so easy... I haven't thought about it.

Comment: But there is still one simple problem - limiting is a *feature* - it have to has the same algorithm.
Btw i have solved the problem just adding `sequential().limit(1)` when i wanted it to be limited

Comment: There is no requirement for a “feature” to have the same algorithm as another feature. The fact that `limit` performs bad in parallel execution has been documented, so while the inability to optimize this specific scenario internally might be indeed surprising, it is in line with the documentation. Calling `sequential().limit(1)` is baroque, you can achieve the same by removing `.parallel()` in the first place. Still, a sized stream may perform better than an infinite stream with limit even with sequential execution for some operations, e.g. it makes a difference for `toArray()`…

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately this is expected behavior. As I remember I've seen at least two topics on this matter, here is [one of them](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33929363/best-way-performance-wise-to-use-limit-on-stream-in-case-of-multithreading).

The idea is that `Stream.generate` creates an `unordered infinite stream` and `limit` will not introduce the `SIZED` flag. Because of this when you spawn a `parallel` execution on that Stream, individual tasks have to sync their execution to see if they have reached that limit; by the time that sync happens there could be multiple elements already processed. For example this:

```
 Stream.iterate(0, x -> x + 1)
            .peek(System.out::println)
            .parallel()
            .limit(2)
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

and this :

```
IntStream.of(1, 2, 3, 4)
            .peek(System.out::println)
            .parallel()
            .limit(2)
            .boxed()
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

will always generate two elements in the `List` (`Collectors.toList`) and *will always* output two elements also (via `peek`).

On the other hand this:

```
Stream<Integer> stream = Stream.generate(new Random()::nextInt).parallel();

List<Integer> list = stream
            .peek(x -> {
                System.out.println("Before " + x);
            })
            .map(x -> {
                System.out.println("Mapping x " + x);
                return x;
            })
            .peek(x -> {
                System.out.println("After " + x);
            })
            .limit(2)
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

will generate two elements in the `List`, but it may process many more that later will be discarded by the `limit`. This is what you are actually seeing in your example.

The only sane way of going that (as far as I can tell) would be to create a custom Spliterator. I have not written many of them, but here is my attempt:

```
 static class LimitingSpliterator<T> implements Spliterator<T> {

    private int limit;

    private final Supplier<T> generator;

    private LimitingSpliterator(Supplier<T> generator, int limit) {
        Preconditions.checkArgument(limit > 0);
        this.limit = limit;
        this.generator = Objects.requireNonNull(generator);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean tryAdvance(Consumer<? super T> consumer) {
        if (limit == 0) {
            return false;
        }
        T nextElement = generator.get();
        --limit;
        consumer.accept(nextElement);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public LimitingSpliterator<T> trySplit() {

        if (limit <= 1) {
            return null;
        }

        int half = limit >> 1;
        limit = limit - half;
        return new LimitingSpliterator<>(generator, half);
    }

    @Override
    public long estimateSize() {
        return limit >> 1;
    }

    @Override
    public int characteristics() {
        return SIZED;
    }
}
```

And the usage would be:

```
 StreamSupport.stream(new LimitingSpliterator<>(new Random()::nextInt, 7), true)
            .peek(System.out::println)
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: Ok, thank you for the answer. However, that just explained me why my solution has errors. But, as i mentioned, limiting is just a *feature* - it has to look for solution infinity, so i cannot state on that solution. Any other idea (reactive for example?)

Comment: By the way, curious thing is when i add `limit(2)` it returns about 1000 solutions, when i chain it with another `limit(2)` for example, it will return maybe 8-10 (random), but after another chaining no difference...

Comment: @Azbesciak 1) no - I can't tell if there is a way to do it with `RxJava` and 2) those `limit.limit` might be just simple `samples` that you get : the behavior is undefined and there are no guarantees for that...

Comment: It’s much easier than writing a custom `Spliterator`. Just keep in mind that mapping operations have no impact on the splitability or SIZED characteristics. So the canonical solution always leads to something along `IntStream.range(0, limit).map…(unused -> actualGeneratorFunction)` (or `LongStream…`, respectively)…